# LOAD DATA INFILE Performance Degrading

Tags: performance, innodb, bulk-insert

I have very little database experience, but I've inherited a database for a production system that has major problems that I am attempting to fix.

The system receives a continuous stream of data from internet of things devices that my company uses to monitor manufacturing equipment. Each record is 180 bytes, and I receive about 200 million records per day (~36 GB/day, ~2300 records/sec). I receive the data in a csv file with 20,000 records, where each record is a device ID and the sensor's data. The csv format maps directly to our database schema for the device sensor readings, so LOAD DATA INFILE is used to directly import the data. The record's primary key is explicitly set in the csv, so there is no auto increment locking occurring.

When each record is loaded, a query is done to look for records from the same device ID over the last day. The records returned from the query are post-processed to calculate additional data that is stored in a separate table. The longer the data is stored in our database, the less likely it is to be queried. I'd say data more than 3 days old is rarely queried. However, a few times a month I am asked to retrieve all the data for a given sensor for the last 6 months.

When the database is empty, LOAD DATA INFILE can load about 40,000 records per second. As the database grows this insert rate decreases. After about 2 months the insert rate drops below 2,000 records per second and my system cannot keep up with the incoming data. My team has been dealing with this by moving the database off of the server, and recreating an empty database. This is extremely problematic when I'm asked to do a 6 month report on a device.

In my dev environment I have resigned the database to use partitioning. I partition the data by week, so I can attempt to keep 6 months of data in the database (I read it's best to have less than 50 partitions). I decided to use partitioning to, at the very least, allow me to age off data gracefully. I assumed partitioning would also solve the LOAD DATA INFILE slowdown, but after running with my new design for 3 weeks, I can already see the performance degrading.

Some details about my database configuration:

MySQL 5.5 with 256 GB of RAM on the server

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 32
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 138G
innodb_io_capacity = 4000
innodb_file_per_table = ON
```

My create table is:

```
CREATE TABLE 'sensor_data' (
'id' bigint(20) NOT NULL,
'sensor_id' varchar(11) NOT NULL,
'datetime' datetime NOT NULL,
'date' date NOT NULL,
'seconds_of_day' double NOT NULL,
'a' double NOT NULL,
'b' int(11) NOT NULL,
'c' int(11) NOT NULL,
'd' double NOT NULL,
'e' double NOT NULL,
'f' int(11) NOT NULL,
'd' int(11) NOT NULL,
'h' double NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id','date'),
KEY 'sensor_data_seconds' ('seconds_of_day','sensor_id','date'),
KEY 'sensor_data_sensor_id' ('sensor_id')
) ENGINE = InnoDB
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(DATE))
(PARTITION sensor_data_y0000w00 VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
PARTITION sensor_data_y2020w13 VALUES LESS THAN (737879) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

My LOAD DATA command looks like:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE CHECKS = 0;
LOAD DATA CONCURRENT LOCAL INFILE <csv> INTO TABLE snesor_data;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
SET UNIQUE CHECKS = 1;
```

I'd like to figure out how I can maintain 6 months (~36 billion records) of data and keep the database performing at > 2,000 inserts per second

Specifically, my questions are:

- Can I use a temporary table, or short term table, to improve performance?

I've seen this suggested on many blogs, but I don't understand how to implement this in practice or why it works. If I held the 20,000 records in a temporary table and performed my queries to queue them up for post processing then copied the table to the long term sensor record storage table, or if I held a week of data in an "active partition" and then moved the partition to the long term storage table at the end of the week, wouldn't the copy perform the same operations as LOAD DATA INFILE? The same indexes would have to be computed and the long term table would still be too large to hold in memory.

- Shouldn't the innodb buffer pool act like a short term storage table?

My understanding is the innodb buffer pool holds recently accessed data. If I'm always looking over the last day for records for the same sensor, shouldn't this data be in the innodb buffer pool?

- Does an entire table's index need to fit in the innodb buffer pool? Or can the index for a given partition be held in the pool?
- Does LOAD DATA INFILE make it difficult for InnoDB to predict what it needs in the buffer pool?
- I've read several blogs that claim it's easy to maintain a large number of records when old data is unlikely to be queried, but none of them said how to do this. How is this handled in practice?
- What else can I do to maintain insert performance as the database grows?

**EDIT:** I somehow mixed up my user accounts, so this was posted from a guest account so I can't comment. This database is on a standalone network, so I can't copy and paste any SHOW STATUS commands. What variables would be interesting to look at? I will post them.

Comment: Can you include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`? A pastie.org link to `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` might be useful as would `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. What storage do you have? Because innodb_io_capacity looks too low for anything modern. Partitioning doesn't gain much beyond the ability to delete/replace partitions quickly.

Comment: Please read [how you can merge your accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)